# LambdaTest Appium Integration : Driver session Response code 400. Message: unsupported platfrom ANDROID

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, lambdatest

I have configured my automation app to run appium on lambdatest.
But I am getting the below error where it is unable to create the driver session

```
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[{browserName=Chrome, appium:deviceName=Google Pixel 7 Pro, platformName=ANDROID, appium:platformVersion=13}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: Chrome, deviceName: Google Pixel 7 Pro, platformName: ANDROID, platformVersion: 13}}]
Capabilities {browserName: Chrome, deviceName: Google Pixel 7 Pro, platformName: ANDROID, platformVersion: 13}
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 400. Message: unsupported platfrom ANDROID
```

The platform name in my code is Android but it gets converted to all caps internally.
I am running the below selenium and appium versions.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.1</version> <!-- Specify the desired version -->
        </dependency>
```

Please let me know if there are any workarounds or any lower versions with which this might execute.

Comment: This above error was due to incorrect lambdatest url for mobile. Once corrected, this still doesn't seem to return the driver. Getting this error now:  `Capabilities {browserName: Chrome, deviceName: Pixel 7 Pro, isRealMobile: true, name: android Pixel 7 Pro 13, platformName: ANDROID, platformVersion: 13}
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 400. Message: platform name is missing in the capabilities`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired capabilities details had to be passed as a map along with a w3c parameter for this to work. Given below is the code that worked for me.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
HashMap<String, Object> ltOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
ltOptions.put("w3c", true);
ltOptions.put("platformName", "android");
ltOptions.put("deviceName", "Pixel 6");
ltOptions.put("platformVersion", "13");
ltOptions.put("isRealMobile", true);
capabilities.setCapability("lt:options", ltOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "android");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Pixel 3");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9");
capabilities.setCapability("isRealMobile", true);
```

[Caps generator](https://www.lambdatest.com/capabilities-generator/)

change ANDROID to android

Comment: Irrespective of the case, it seems to always take it as caps when it is set into DesiredCapabilities.

Comment: This above error was due to incorrect lambdatest url for mobile. Once corrected, this still doesn't seem to return the driver. Getting this error now:  `Capabilities {browserName: Chrome, deviceName: Pixel 7 Pro, isRealMobile: true, name: android Pixel 7 Pro 13, platformName: ANDROID, platformVersion: 13}
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 400. Message: platform name is missing in the capabilities`